# ¿Cómo puedo retornar una suma de dos valores numéricos que el usuario ingrese?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, cmd, input

El problema es que, básicamente, estoy comenzando con la programación en JavaScript usando el entorno Node.js, y tengo un código que, según yo, al recibir dos números enteros debería devolver a la consola la suma de estos, pero en lugar de eso es como si literalmente se concatenaran los valores en vez de sumarse, lo cual es lo que necesito en este caso.

```
const readline = require('readline');
const rl = readline.createInterface({ input: process.stdin, output: process.stdout });

rl.question('Ingresa el primer numero: ', (a) => {
    if(!a) {
        console.log('Necesitas ingresar ambos numeros para poder hacer la suma.');
        return rl.close();
    }
    if(a <= 0) {
        console.log('Ambos numeros deben ser positivos y mayores a cero!');
        return rl.close();
    }
    if(isNaN(a)) {
        console.log('Debes escribir un numero!');
        return rl.close();
    }
    rl.question('Ingresa el segundo numero: ', (b) => {
        if(!b) {
            console.log('Necesitas ingresar ambos numeros para poder hacer la suma.');
            return rl.close();
        }
        if(b <= 0) {
            console.log('Ambos numeros deben ser positivos y mayores a cero!');
            return rl.close();
        }
        if(isNaN(b)) {
            console.log('Debes escribir un numero!');
            return rl.close();
        }
        let suma = a + b;
        console.log(`El resultado de la suma es ${suma}.`);
        return rl.close();
    });
});
```

El resultado que esperaría es que, por ejemplo, si en el primer número (a) se escribe un "5" y en segundo número (b) se escribe un "6", el último `console.log()` retornaría un "11", pero en lugar de eso lo que se obtiene es un "56".

Answer (score 1):

Leyendo los objetos globales, encontré la respuesta a mi propia pregunta.
Los valores que se reciben de `readline` siempre son strings (cadenas), por lo que es necesario convertir dichos strings a valores de tipo numérico.
Para esto simplemente usé `Number()`.
Directo de la documentación:
"Los principales usos del objeto `Number(valor)` son convertir un string u otro valor a uno de tipo numérico; si el argumento no puede ser convertido a un número, devuelve `NaN`."

Por lo que en mi código, tan solo tuve que cambiar unas cosas en la declaración `let` de la suma:

```
let suma = Number(a) + Number(b);
```

Y con eso fue suficiente para que funcione como esperado. Ahora los valores se suman en vez de concatenarse, porque ahora son números en vez de strings.